# Put check-box in end of a line in markdown file

Tags: github, markdown

I'm wondering if there's a way to put the check-box(TODO) at the end of a line in a markdown file.
for example:

```
1- First Task - [ ]
2- Second Task - [ ]
```

Comment: Is that even valid Markdown / GFM? I'm referring to both the first dash on the line as well as the `[ ]` at the end.

Comment: As you know we can make todo with `- [ ]`. And that is a simple for that thing i need. My propose was about put a todo at the end of line with GitHub Mark down.

Comment: Ah. That's GFM. Thanks! (I doubt I'll use  it as it has limited portability.)

Comment: your welcome. `I doubt I'll use it as it has limited portability.` you mean there's no way to make a file like this?

Comment: No. I just wonder if almost all Markdown processors handle this syntax. (Not all because mine, for example, doesn't.)

Comment: Yes the example doesn't and i put that example to show what i need